# Can't do a lookup for JNDI

Tags: java, ejb, jndi

I have the following declaration in my `ejb-jar.xml`

```xml
<enterprise-beans>

        <entity>
            <description>Simple CMP Entity bean example</description>
            <ejb-name>CalculatorBean</ejb-name>
            <remote>ejb3.stateless.CalculatorRemote</remote>
            <ejb-class>ejb3.stateless.CalculatorBean</ejb-class>
            <persistence-type>Container</persistence-type>
            <prim-key-class>java.lang.Integer</prim-key-class>
            <reentrant>false</reentrant>
        </entity>
 </enterprise-beans>
```

And I tried to do a look up from my servlet as follows;

```
 CalculatorRemote calculator = (CalculatorRemote)ic.lookup("java/comp/env/:CalculatorBean");
```

But it says the name specified cannot be found.

I have created classes for `CalculatorRemote` and also `CalculatorBean`.

Here is `CalculatorRemote`

```
@Remote
public interface CalculatorRemote {

    public float add(float x, float y);

    public float subtract(float x, float y);

    public float multiply(float x, float y);

    public float division(float x, float y);
}
```

`CalculatorBean` is an implementation of `CalculatorRemote`. ic is InitialContext.

Comment: Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I & proper names like Java, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: Add more information, what is the CalculatorRemote? Have you tried lookup("CalculatorBean") ? What is ic?

Comment: ic.lookup("CalculatorBean") didn't work. I have re-edited the original post to add the details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to lookup Bean

```
 CalculatorRemote calculator = (CalculatorRemote)ic.lookup("java:comp/env/CalculatorBean");
```

EDIT:

for GlassFish no need add 
Remove the `java:comp/env/` part.

```
 CalculatorRemote calculator = (CalculatorRemote)ic.lookup("CalculatorBean");
```

Comment: Still same error: "Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/CalculatorBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}"

Comment: which server  you are using